# SQL - Return 0 value for a grouping

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 tables, Member_School, which holds links between members and schools, Schools which contains school information, and Category which is a simply lookup table for full category names (categories of members).

Im trying to get a count of all member categories for each school, but can't get a 0 count for the categories which have no members in for particular schools. Here's my query so far:

```
WITH MemberNums AS
(
SELECT School_No, Category, COUNT(Member_No) AS NumberOfMembs

FROM Member_School

WHERE Finish_Date > GETDATE()

AND Category IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY School_No, Category

)


SELECT School.School_No, Category.Category, MemberNums.NumberOfMembs AS NumberOfMembs, School.School_Name, School.ATH_No, School.AWA_No, School.CLE_No, School.CYC_No, School.CYF_No, School.OBS_No, School.PEN_No, School.RHI_No, 
School.STA_No, School.SYL_No

FROM School 

INNER JOIN MemberNums 
ON School.School_No = MemberNums.School_No

LEFT JOIN Category
ON Category.Category_No = MemberNums.Category

ORDER BY School_No
```

So for example this query might return 8 rows for the school with ID 123, but there are 10 categories in the Category table. What I'm trying to get would be 10 rows per school, with a count of how many members in each category (including zero counts for schools which have no records for a certain category in the Member_School table)

Here is an example row from each table:

Category:

```
Category_No: Cat1
Category: Category1
```

School:

```
School_No: 123
School_Name: Highschool
Memb_No: 10
Secondary: True
Job_No: XJI314
ATH_No: 1
AWA_No: 1
CLE_No: 1
CYC_No: 1
CYF_No: 1
OBS_No: 1
PEN_No: 1
RHI_No: 1
STA_No: 1
SYL_No: 1
```

Member_School:

```
Rec_No: 1
Member_No: 2
School_No: 123
Start_Date: 2018-03-19 00:00:00.000
End_Date: 2020-03-19 00:00:00.000
Category: Cat1
```

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT JOIN memberNums`?

Comment: Which dbms?  `SQL` is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `cross join` between `Schools` and `Category` so that you get every category for every school. Then use `Member_School` to get the count, if any, of members for each school/category pair.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing.  You mention a count, but your query has nothing resembling a count.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The count is done in the MemberNums CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want zeros, then use a `cross join` to generate the rows then bring in the existing data:

```
select s.School_No, c.Category, count(ms.School_No) as NumberOfMembs as NumberOfMembs,
       s.School_Name, s.ATH_No, s.AWA_No, School.CLE_No,
       s.CYC_No, s.CYF_No, s.OBS_No, s.PEN_No, s.RHI_No, 
       s.STA_No, s.SYL_No
from school s cross join
     categories c left join
     Member_School ms
     on ms.School_No = s.School_No and
        ms.Category = c.Category_No and
        ms.Finish_Date > getdate()
group by s.School_No, c.Category, 
         s.School_Name, s.ATH_No, s.AWA_No, School.CLE_No,
         s.CYC_No, s.CYF_No, s.OBS_No, s.PEN_No, s.RHI_No, 
         s.STA_No, s.SYL_No;
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem exactly but refactoring and using cross join worked

Answer (score 0):

use left join

```
WITH MemberNums AS
(
SELECT School_No, Category, COUNT(Member_No) AS NumberOfMembs

FROM Member_School

WHERE Finish_Date > GETDATE()

AND Category IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY School_No, Category

)    

SELECT School.School_No, Category.Category, MemberNums.NumberOfMembs AS NumberOfMembs, School.School_Name, School.ATH_No, School.AWA_No, School.CLE_No, School.CYC_No, School.CYF_No, School.OBS_No, School.PEN_No, School.RHI_No, 
School.STA_No, School.SYL_No

FROM School 

left JOIN MemberNums 
ON School.School_No = MemberNums.School_No

LEFT JOIN Category
ON Category.Category_No = MemberNums.Category

ORDER BY School_No
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using left join but it doesn't work, still get for example only 8 categories for the first school, 6 for the second school and so on.

Comment: @hjalpmig can you please provide sample data and expected output or you can create fiddle link with your data that will help to solve your problem

Comment: Adadin Tuhin Updates question with data example.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried using a right outer join? Use the right outer join and coalesce function to ensure 0 shows up instead of null.
I've posted a sample query below**

```
WITH MemberNums AS
(
SELECT School_No, Category, COUNT(Member_No) AS NumberOfMembs

FROM Member_School

WHERE Finish_Date > GETDATE()

AND Category IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY School_No, Category

)


SELECT School.School_No, Category.Category, COALESCE(MemberNums.NumberOfMembs, 0) AS NumberOfMembs, School.School_Name, School.ATH_No, School.AWA_No, School.CLE_No, School.CYC_No, School.CYF_No, School.OBS_No, School.PEN_No, School.RHI_No, 
School.STA_No, School.SYL_No

FROM School 

INNER JOIN MemberNums 
ON School.School_No = MemberNums.School_No

RIGHT OUTER JOIN Category
ON Category.Category_No = MemberNums.Category

ORDER BY School_No
```

**If you want all results from school and member_school that may not have a category, then you might want to consider FULL OUTER JOIN instead**

Comment: Hi, both right outer and full outer joins still don't give me 10 categories for each school